# Converting mathtype equations from word docx to word equations using ruby

Tags: xml-parsing, docx, pandoc, mathjax, mathtype

I am trying to convert Docx to Html,
but the Docx might contain images, MathType equations in WMF format and word equations in `tex` format with `$` delimiters.

I have tried converting Docx to Html using pandoc and LibreOffice:

Problems using pandoc:
Pandoc skip MathType equations so I had to read document.xml and convert WMF to png using `gimp's convert` command line tool.

This puts some of the equations in very unreadable format.

Problems using libreoffice:
It actually converts whole documents to HTML very nicely, but word equations get cut from sides during conversion.

What I want is some tool that can convert Docx to Html, and it converts MathType equations as well as word equations both to `tex` format.

I want to do this preferably in ruby, but any workaround or ideas are most welcome as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The pandoc docx reader [supports only](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/x3jMRSke53U) OMML math, not the old MathType.

You could write a [pandoc filter](http://pandoc.org/scripting.html) that finds the math in the pandoc AST (it will be there as plain text) and convert them to [pandoc math elements](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-types/blob/master/Text/Pandoc/Definition.hs#L260) which the pandoc LaTeX writer will automatically convert to TeX math.